# Determining Whether $T$ is Linear and an Isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have $T(M) = M\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2\\3 & 4\end{pmatrix}M$ from $\mathbb{R}^{2\times2} \rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{2\times2}$.  I need to determine if $T$ is linear and, if so, if $T$ is an isomorphism.

Arbitrarily defining two matrices $X=\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{pmatrix}, Y=\begin{pmatrix}e & f\\g & h\end{pmatrix}$ and showing that $T(X) + T(Y) \neq T(X+Y)$ requires a ton of algebra, but it seems to be the case. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: Try a simple case first. If it was linear, then $T(\lambda M) = \lambda M$. From above, we see that $T(\lambda M) = \lambda^2 T(M)$, so if $T(M) \neq 0$ for some $M$, then it cannot be linear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's enough to find a counterexample.

Use the identity matrix. Show that $T(I+I)\neq T(I)+T(I)$.

Answer (score 1):

Our map $T:\Bbb R^{2\times 2}\to\Bbb R^{2\times 2}$ is defined by $T(M)=MAM$ where
$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&2\\3&4
\end{bmatrix}
$.

Note that 
$$
T(2\,I)=(2\,I)A(2\,I)=4\,A\neq 2\,A=2\,(IAI)=2\,T(I)
$$
so $T$ is not linear.

Answer (score 0):

You have: $T(M)=MAM$  where $A$ is an invertible not diagonal matrice, so, $\forall \lambda \ne 0$ you have:
$$
T(\lambda M)=(\lambda M)A(\lambda M)= \lambda^2 MAM = \lambda^2 T(M)
$$
and the tranformation is not linear.